# Ineed a SSH format command line of php to upload files to WinSCP FTP, I need ur ideas or get rid of this probs

Tags: php, ssh, winscp

Here is my code , that i have done so far needed ur guidance urgently.....

I already have d ftp server space, al i need now is a good command line for uploading to that WinSCP ftp....

```
<html>
<body>

<?php


if(isset($_FILES["uploaded"]))
{
print_r($_FILES);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"],"/sigaindia.com/public_html/reymend/".$_FILES["uploaded"]["name"])) 
echo "FILE UPLOADED!";
}
else
{
 print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='fup1.php' method='POST'>";
 print "File:<input name='uploaded' type='file'/><input type='submit' value='Upload'/>";
 print "</form>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Kindly do d needful frnds..... expecting ur ideas badly.....

Comment: Please clarify what you are talking about. What is the problem, what does it have to do with WinSCP, and what doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command to upload a file with WinSCP by FTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884004/command-to-upload-a-file-with-winscp-by-ftp) Please do not post duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused, but what I think you're asking for is a shell script to run that transfers a previously uploaded file?

If so, something as simple as the [Linux cp](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm) command will do, it allows you to copy files to another location.

eg make a copy.sh with these contents, (chmod +x to make it executable as well):

```
cp /path/to/filename.txt /path/to/new/newfile.txt
```

You can then run this command from the shell with `./copy.sh` or inside PHP with the exec() command or even regularly with a crontab.
If you need to do this in PHP, you can use the [copy()](http://uk.php.net/copy) function.